# How can I get pointer type behaviour in python

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I want to write a test case which will test a list of functions.
Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
from mock import Mock
def method1 ():
    pass

def method2 ():
    pass

## The testcase will then contain:
for func in method_list:
    func = Mock()
    # continue to setup the mock and do some testing
```

What I want to achieve is as follows:
Step 1) Assign my local method variable to each item in method_list
Step 2) Monkeypatch the method.  In this example I am using a mock.Mock object

What actually occurs is:
Step 1) method is successfully assigned to an item from method_list - OK
Step 2) method is then assigned to the object Mock() - NOK

What I wanted in step 2 was to get the item from method_list e.g. method1 to be assigned to the Mock() object.  The end result would be that both method and method1 would point to the same Mock() object

I realise that what I am essentially doing is 
a = b
a = c
and then expecting c==b !

I guess this is not really possible with out somehow getting a pointer to b ?

Comment: Still not quite clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @awithrow, I have 2 methods in a list.  I want to monkeypatch each method.  I can do this with hardcoding the method names e.g.
method1 = Mock()
# run a test
method2 = Mock()
# run the test again

Is it possible to use a a variable to represent the method an then patch the method via the variable ?

Comment: a function is a Python object. Variables, like `method1`, point to that object. It seems that what you want to do is to change what the variable `method1` points to; this is *possible* but rarely a good idea. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to change what the *variable* `method1` points to? Is that right?

You can do this by modifying its entry in the dictionary of local variables:

```
for method_name in [ 'method1', 'method2' ]:
    locals()[ method_name ] = Mock( )
```

The reason your previous code doesn't do what you want is that `func` is a reference to the function `method1`. By assigning to is, you simply change what it points to.

#### Are you sure you want to do this?

Monkeypatching is nasty and can cause many problems.

Comment: that's a neat trick with locals(), I hadn't though to approach it like that.  Yeah, monkeypatching can have unwanted side effects if you are not careful, but I'm using this for a test suite and it is just really useful for isolation.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Um, how about simply modifiying method_list?

```
for i in range(len(method_list)): # xrange in Python 2
    method_list[i] = Mock()
```

What you describe is closer to C++ references than to pointers. Few languages have such semantics (a few provide a special keyword for pass-by-reference), including Python.

Comment: I think your solution has the same problem that I encounter.  By setting method_list[i] to Mock() you have set the item at index i to be Mock(), whereas the old item at index i was not modified at all.  But your input is very much appreciated

Comment: @ephesian If you really want to modify *all* references to a specific object, then it's just not possible. Is the problem that e.g. `method1` still refers to the same function? Then see katrielalex's post.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
from mock import Mock
def method1 ():
    pass

def method2 ():
    pass

method_list=list(f for f in globals() if hasattr(globals()[f],'__call__') and f.startswith('method'))
print method_list
## The testcase will then contain:
for func in method_list:
    globals()[func] = Mock(func)
    # continue to setup the mock and do some testing
```

I am not so sure this is sensible thing to do, though. Looks like something to do with decorators.

Comment: thanks, that is a useful way to get the list of methods.  Unfortunately they don't all start with the same string, but I get the idea